# Outputting a value after each iterations in R

Tags: r, loops, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to output the misclassification of my neural network using 10 different seeds, after each iteration inside the loop I am trying to output the value of misrate.test which is the misclassification. Here is preview of the data + code snippet,I called the data new.train I can't the that value after running my program

```
   V1    V70    V30    V86    V22   V107    V46    V78    V94    V62    V91    
   V76
   4   7  1.000 -0.421  0.931 -0.114 -0.186  1.000  0.695 -0.363  1.000 
   -0.949 -0.606
   11  7  1.000  1.000  1.000 -0.973 -1.000  0.167 -0.121  0.265 -0.415 
   -1.000 -1.000
   15  7 -0.870 -1.000 -0.289 -1.000 -0.279 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 
   -0.715  0.918
   16  7  0.758 -1.000 -0.535  0.901  0.508 -0.786 -0.913 -1.000 -0.796 
   -0.293  0.913
   23  7  0.047  0.531 -0.983  0.212 -0.965  1.000  0.343 -0.427  0.993 
   -1.000 -0.857
   26  7 -0.158  0.912 -1.000 -0.173  0.469 -0.117 -1.000 -1.000 -0.977 
   -0.020  0.974


library(nnet)
diff.seed <- c(1,66,70,222,1345,766,453,2999,7654,10000)
for(i in diff.seed){
set.seed(i) #Set different seed
digit.nnet <- nnet(V1~., data=new.train, size = 5, rang=0.1, decay=5e-4, 
maxit=1000) #Train the network on new.train

y.hat <- as.numeric(predict(digit.nnet,new.test, type = "class")) #Apply on 
new.test which is same as new.train

misrate.test <- sum(y.hat != 
new.test[,1])/length(new.test[,1])#Misclassification rate 
misrate.test #Attempt to output it
}
```

Comment: Can you use [`cat`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html), [`print`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.html), [`message`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/message.html), or [`warning`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warning.html)? Or are looking to capture all `misrate.test` into a vector, perhaps using [`lapply` or `sapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html)?

Comment: Try using `print(misrate.test)` inside your `for` loop

Comment: I am just trying to get the different values for `misrate.test` after each iteration putting them into a vector would work too

Comment: BTW: conceptually, unless you are trying to prove empirically that classification is sensitive to the random state, it seems odd that you are fishing for a particular mis-classification rate (analytically-speaking). If this were a homework assignment, I'd be concerned about fishing for better "random results". (I'm probably way off base here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your question exactly (do not have `new.test`), but one of these should work:

```
library(nnet)
diff.seed <- c(1,66,70,222,1345,766,453,2999,7654,10000)
for(i in diff.seed) {
  set.seed(i) #Set different seed
  digit.nnet <- nnet(V1~., data=new.train, size = 5, rang=0.1, decay=5e-4, maxit=1000) #Train the network on new.train
  y.hat <- as.numeric(predict(digit.nnet,new.test, type = "class")) #Apply on new.test which is same as new.train

  misrate.test <- sum(y.hat != new.test[,1])/length(new.test[,1])#Misclassification rate 
  print(misrate.test) #Attempt to output it
}
```

or

```
misrates <- sapply(diff.seed, function(i) {
  set.seed(i) #Set different seed
  digit.nnet <- nnet(V1~., data=new.train, size = 5, rang=0.1, decay=5e-4, maxit=1000) #Train the network on new.train
  y.hat <- as.numeric(predict(digit.nnet,new.test, type = "class")) #Apply on new.test which is same as new.train

  misrate.test <- sum(y.hat != new.test[,1])/length(new.test[,1])#Misclassification rate 
  misrate.test
})
```

Comment: new.test is the same data set as new.train

Comment: For the *effect*, perhaps it doesn't really matter what the test data is. Have you tried either of these methods? Which is closer to your intended outcome?

Comment: as crazy as it sounds just wrapping print around misrate made it work lool thanks for the help

Comment: That's what I suspected, I'm glad it worked for you. I still recommend that you use the second technique and capture the values; it is a functional mechanism that allows you to do things with the values programmatically instead of manually interpreting. For instance, you could easily say `diff.seed[which.min(misrates)]` to get just the "best seed" of the bunch. With only a few seeds this seems trivial, but if you ever extend to many more (100s or more), having it accessible in this fashion will save considerable time and effort.